# IPhone - Setting NSString from array, double standards!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the following bit of code, I'm setting the table view cell text with a value from the NSMutableArray 'categories' which is a property of my view controller.  That works fine.

But when I try the exact same code in another method, it crashes (it compiles without errors or warnings).  If I change the following line in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
NSString *categoryName = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to

```
NSString *categoryName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
```

It works... any ideas?

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

 // Configure the cell.
 NSString *categoryName = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = categoryName;

    return cell;
}




// Override to support row selection in the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    printf("User selected row %d\n", [indexPath row] + 1);

 ButtonsPageViewController *bView =  [ButtonsPageViewController alloc];
 NSLog(@"created instance of buttonspageviewcontroller");

 NSString *categoryName = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSLog(@"category name set");

 bView.selectedCategory = categoryName;
 NSLog(@"selected category property set");

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:bView animated:YES];
 NSLog(@"push view controller");

 [bView release];
}
```

Comment: what does the crash say ..say 'backtrace' in the console when the crash happens and paste that in the question, that would be helpful

Comment: And what *is* `[categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`? Have you looked at this in a debugger? Or even just NSLog debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between

```
NSString *categoryName = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and

```
NSString *categoryName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
```

Is that the first line copies a pointer to the object (retain count does not change) whereas the second one creates a new object (retain count = 1).

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, when you set the `text` property, it copies or retains the string, so you're fine. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you are setting a property of `ButtonsPageViewController`, which I assume is your own code, but perhaps it is not copying or retaining the object.

Also, the line

```
ButtonsPageViewController *bView =  [ButtonsPageViewController alloc];
```

is going to lead to problems. You need to call `init` to properly initialize the object. All you've done in that line is allocate memory for it.

In general, it looks like you need to brush up on Retain/Release memory management. That should save you some trouble.

Comment: I did have bView initialising properly before, I've now initialised it.  I agree, I do need to brush up on memory management!

Comment: I got it!

You were right about the memory management.  I retained the category array and it's working now.

Thanks for helping out a relative noob! Kudos to you :D

Answer (score 1):

Like benzado says, it's an issue retaining the `selectedCategory` value in `ButtonsPageViewController`.

Are you using `@property` and `@synthesize` or are you writing your own accessors? If it's the former, you probably need to look at the property declaration attributes. Otherwise, it's probably a retain/release thing in your custom accessor.

The [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) section of [The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Laungauge](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2) is a good resource for rules of declaring synthesized accessors.